# LINAC: why are they being accelerated?

Tags: accelerator-physics, electromagnetism

I have read the wiki page and I have seen [this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lineaer_accelerator_en.svg), but I still don't understand why they are being accelerated.

[image]

Could you easily explain it to me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you mean why the particles feel the need that they have to obey some laws and accelerate, i.e. what's the mechanism, well, there is an RF source (radio frequencies) which bring an electric force in the direction of the acceleration at the place where the particle is located. The electric force implies acceleration $ma=qE$. If you mean Why do people accelerate them, what's the goal, well, they need high-energy particles because the energy is needed to to create interesting processes and new particles.

Answer (score 1):

The electrons are negatively charged. Like charges repel. Opposite charges attract. In the top diagram, you see negative electrons attracted towards the positive electrode (the orange cylinder with the +) and repelled by the negative electrode (the orange cylinder with the -). So the electrons are accelerated.

There could be a problem, however; will the electron remain attracted to the positive electrode and stop accelerating?

No! Because the charges of the electrodes are switched from negative <-> positive at high frequency, with perfect timing so that once the electron passes the positive electrode, it switches negative, and the electron is repelled by it. This is the lower diagram.

Comment: maybe you could incorporate "As the particle bunch passes through the tube it is unaffected (the tube acts as a Faraday cage), while the frequency of the driving signal and the spacing of the gaps between electrodes are designed so that the maximum voltage differential appears as the particle crosses the gap. This accelerates the particle, imparting energy to it in the form of increased velocity." from the wiki article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_accelerator from which the image is taken.